# Running an executable in chroot environment gives: " Error 24"

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, chroot

I am trying to execute a program from python using subprocess module as follows :

```
scommand = "echo 12 | sudo -kS chroot "+out.split("media")[0]+"media "+ out.split("media")[1]
subprocess.Popen([scommand], stdin=p1.stdout, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE ,preexec_fn=hsafelimits)
```

But it gives me an error :

```
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: Error 24
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: It just told you the reason.  `error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file`

Comment: It looks like your chroot isn't setup properly (it doesn't have a copy of libc.so.6 for instance). Does this work from the command line?

Comment: yes this works from command line

Comment: I'm at a loss. Since you can do the chroot from the shell, and python is calling a sub-shell to do the chroot, they should operate similarly. You might have problems because python isn't using a pty, but that doesn't matter for finding libc.